# what is the use of manifest.json in react.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

My firebase hosted page is rendering a blank page. The console says there are some problem in manifest.json. Can anyone please help in figuring it out.

```
    {
      "short_name": "React App",
      "name": "Create React App Sample",
      "icons": [
        {
          "src": "favicon.ico",
          "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
          "type": "image/x-icon"
        },
        {
          "src": "logo192.png",
          "type": "image/png",
          "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
          "src": "logo512.png",
          "type": "image/png",
          "sizes": "512x512"
        }
      ],
      "start_url": ".",
      "display": "standalone",
      "theme_color": "#000000",
      "background_color": "#ffffff"
    }
```

The errors in console are [image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Please post the errors as text in the question, not as images.

Comment: I'm sorry for the images, now solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to debug and solve the issue, actually there was some misconfiguration in the firebase installation.

1. Deleted firebase.json
2. run firebase init
3. Set the deploy target as from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets
   firebase target:apply TYPE TARGET_NAME RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER
   Where the parameters are:

TYPE — the relevant Firebase resource type

For Firebase Hosting sites, use hosting.
TARGET_NAME — a unique name for the Hosting site that you're deploying to

RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER — the SITE_ID for the Hosting site as listed in your Firebase project

For example, if you've created two sites (myapp-blog and myapp-app) in your Firebase project, you could apply a unique TARGET_NAME (blog and app, respectively) to each site by running the following commands:

> > firebase target:apply hosting blog myapp-blog
> > firebase target:apply hosting app myapp-app

4. Then created deploy target in the array of firebase.json

```js
{
  "hosting": [ {
      "target": "blog",  // "blog" is the applied TARGET_NAME for the Hosting site "myapp-blog"
      "public": "blog/dist",  // contents of this folder are deployed to the site "myapp-blog"

      // ...
    },
    {
      "target": "app",  // "app" is the applied TARGET_NAME for the Hosting site "myapp-app"
      "public": "app/dist",  // contents of this folder are deployed to the site "myapp-app"

      // ...

      "rewrites": [...]  // You can define specific Hosting configurations for each site
    }
  ]
}

{
  "storage": [ {
      "target": "main",  // "main" is the applied TARGET_NAME for the group of Cloud Storage buckets
      "rules": "storage.main.rules"  // the file that contains the shared security rules
    }
  ]
}
```

5. The I used,

> > npm run build
> > 6.  Then run,
> > firebase deploy